# Dynamically change chart colors using colorpicker

Tags: java, javafx

I want to dynamically change colors of different type charts, using colorpicker. Then I made sample code like this for pie chart.

***Color picker action listener:***

```
        colorPicker.setOnAction(event -> {           

        Node node = chart.lookup(".default-color0.chart-pie");
        String str = "-fx-pie-color:" + toRGBCode(colorPicker.getValue()) + ";";

        node.setStyle(str);
    });
```

***CSS file:***

```
.default-color0.chart-pie { -fx-pie-color: #ffd700; }
.default-color1.chart-pie { -fx-pie-color: #ffa500; }
.default-color2.chart-pie { -fx-pie-color: #860061; }
.default-color3.chart-pie { -fx-pie-color: #adff2f; }
.default-color4.chart-pie { -fx-pie-color: #ff5700; }
```

It works fine but only partially. Problem is that, when I'm changing the color, the legend of chart doesn't follow it. How to dynamically update legend?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can update the legend by obtaining it after it has been drawn via a node lookup and then modifying its style similar to what you have already done in the question

This answer is built on what you have provided so there is the assumption you know which item you want to update as you know the style class in this line:

```
Node node = chart.lookup(".default-color0.chart-pie");
```

So with that in mind, you can do something similar with the following:

```
public static void updateChartLegendColorFromItemName(Chart chart, String itemToUpdate, Color legendColor){
        Set<Node> legendItems = chart.lookupAll("Label.chart-legend-item");
        if(legendItems.isEmpty()){ return; }
        String styleString = "-fx-background-color:" + toRGBCode(legendColor) + ";";
        for(Node legendItem : legendItems){
            Label legendLabel = (Label) legendItem;
            Node legend = legendLabel.getGraphic(); //The legend icon (circle by default)

            if(legend != null && legendLabel.getText().equals(itemToUpdate)){
                legend.setStyle(styleString);
            }
        }
    }
```

An example usage from what you've provided would be:

```
colorPicker.setOnAction(event -> {
            Node node = chart.lookup(".default-color0.chart-pie");
            String styleString = "-fx-background-color:" + toRGBCode(colorPicker.getValue()) + ";";
            node.setStyle(styleString);
            updateChartLegendColorFromItemName(chart, "Sunday", colorPicker.getValue());
        });
```

Hopefully this helps

Answer (score 0):

There is a private method `updateLegend()` in `PieChart` class that is called when chart data or their names are modified.  This method creates new legend items for every `PieChart.Data` object and loads their styles from the data object’s styleClass:

```
for (Data item : getData()) {
    LegendItem legenditem = new LegendItem(item.getName());
    legenditem.getSymbol().getStyleClass().addAll(item.getNode().getStyleClass());
    legenditem.getSymbol().getStyleClass().add("pie-legend-symbol");
    legend.getItems().add(legenditem);
}
```

It means that calling `setStyle()` on chart’s data objects will have no effect on the legend color.
You could try to modify the legend objects directly but your change will probably be cancelled the next time updateLegend() is called unless you modify the style class of the pie’s node that you changed. Below is an example of how to change the color of the first pie and its legend item to the color that is already defined in your style sheet (e.g. the color of the second pie):

```
// reference to the first pie's node
Node node = chart.lookup(".default-color0.chart-pie");
// the default-color property is in the third line. It is defined by
// updateDataItemStyleClass(final Data item, int index) method in PieChart class
node.getStyleClass().set(2, "default-color1");
// we have to trigger some change so updateLegend() is called:
String name0 = pieChartData.get(0).getName();
pieChartData.get(0).setName("");
pieChartData.get(0).setName(name0);
```

To make this method work for your purpose you will need to update your CSS file (or create another one) in your `ColorPicker` handler. I don’t know if it is possible to create new style definitions without creation/modification of CSS files at runtime. The solution definitely does not look elegant but it looks like JavaFX was not designed to easily achieve what you need.